# How to solve changing public to public_html in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I am trying to change the public folder to the public_html folder on Cpanel, and it was working fine in local mode on my computer.

I tried these steps.

1. ./app/AppServiceProvider.php
   add this code

   ```
   public function register(){ $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
   return base_path().'/public_html'; });}
   ```
2. ./config/filesystems.php change public to public_html

   ```
    'public' => ['driver' => 'local','root' =>
     storage_path('app/public'),'url' =>
     env('APP_URL').'/storage','visibility' => 'public',],
   ```
3. ./webpack.mix.js change public to public_html

   ```
    mix.config.publicPath='public_html';
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public_html/js')
          .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public_html/css');
   ```
4. index.php add this code

   ```
   $app->bind('path.public', function() { return __DIR__; });
   ```
5. ./bootstrap/app.php add this code

   ```
   $app->bind('path.public', function() { return base_path().'/public_html'; });
   ```

After running -> npm run dev

It automatically creates a public folder and creates a public_html folder with a mix-manifest.json file in it, and it has this error on the site.

[image: Creates a public folder automatically picture]

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 6):

I've included two different options here, one for just changing the public directory name, and one for also putting the core files in their own directory:

***First Option:* Just renaming the public/ directory, for laravel 9:**

1. Rename public folder to `public_html` (or any desired name)
2. Edit `AppServiceProviver.php` and add below code in register method:

> ```
> $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
>   return realpath(base_path().'/public_html');
> });
> ```

3. Add `publicDirectory: 'public_html'` to `laravel_core/vite.config.js` within the plugins / laravel object, eg.

> ```
> export default defineConfig({
>     plugins: [
>         laravel({
>             publicDirectory: 'public_html', // This is the only new line
>             input: [
>                 'resources/sass/app.scss',
>                 'resources/js/app.js',
>             ],
>             refresh: true,
>         }),
>     ],
> });
> ```

***Second option:* Seperate out the laravel core files into their own directory and also rename the public/ directory, for laravel 9:**

1. Rename public folder to `public_html` (or any desired name)
2. Create a `laravel_core` directory and move all files and folders except `public_html` into the laravel_core folder.
3. Edit `index.php` in `public_html` folder and find/replace `__DIR__.'/../` with `__DIR__.'/../laravel_core/` (3 cases)
4. Edit `AppServiceProviver.php` and add below code in register method:

> ```
> $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
>   return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
> });
> ```

5. Add `publicDirectory: 'public_html'` to `laravel_core/vite.config.js` within the plugins / laravel object, eg.

> ```
> export default defineConfig({
>     plugins: [
>         laravel({
>             publicDirectory: '../public_html',
>             input: [
>                 'resources/sass/app.scss',
>                 'resources/js/app.js',
>             ],
>             refresh: true,
>         }),
>     ],
> });
> ```

### IMPORTANT NOTE FOR LARAVEL 10

In Laravel 10 you will need to also add this line to `bootstrap/app.php`, after the `$app` object is instantiated here on line 14:

> ```
> $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
>     $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
> );
>
> // Add this below:
> $app->usePublicPath($app->basePath('../public_html'));
> ```

Note that I have used `../public_html` here as I have the `laravel_core` files separated into their own directory as shown in the second option above, but if you are just changing the `public` directory name then just use this instead:

> ```
> $app->usePublicPath($app->basePath('public_html'));
> ```