# How do I change public/ directory name in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

I have seen a question with a very similar title on SO from 3 months ago but it has no answers.

After a fresh laravel 9 installation what are the minimum steps to put the laravel application into it's own directory, and also modify the public directory name? It would be handy to have a step by step guide with laravel 9 specific one as I can't seem to find one anywhere.

eg. the following root directory structure:

`laravel-app/ (contains all laravel files like resources/ and storage/)`

`public_html/ (contains index.php and /js etc)`

Using the old process (similar to this https://github.com/hannanstd/change-laravel-public) I have always used no longer works, and this seems to have something to do with vite that laravel 9 uses instead of laravel-mix. It works up to the point of running `php artisan serve` but fails when running `npm run dev` with vite. Giving this error:

```
$ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency 
pre-bundling.
node:internal/fs/utils:347
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public\hot'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:594:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2207:35)
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\Websites\laravel9-admin\laravel-core\node_modules\laravel-vite-plugin\dist\index.js:122:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Server.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at emitListeningNT (node:net:1466:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'public\\hot'
}
```

So it seems that yet somewhere else the default "public/" is defined, but after searching with ctrl+shift+F in my project it doesn't seem to be anywhere that matters so really unsure where it's getting it from. Any help is highly appreciated, but really a step by step guide on how to achieve this for Laravel 9 is the end goal so it can be a reference for myself and other users with the same problem :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve changing public to public\_html in Laravel 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864056/how-to-solve-changing-public-to-public-html-in-laravel-9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this myself as found the solution!

***First Option:* Just rename the public/ directory, for laravel 9:**

1. Rename public folder to `public_html` (or any desired name)
2. Edit `AppServiceProvider.php` and add below code in register method:

> ```
> $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
>   return realpath(base_path().'/public_html');
> });
> ```

3. Add `publicDirectory: 'public_html'` to `laravel-core/vite.config.js` within the plugins / laravel object, eg.

> ```
> export default defineConfig({
>     plugins: [
>         laravel({
>             publicDirectory: 'public_html',
>             input: [
>                 'resources/sass/app.scss',
>                 'resources/js/app.js',
>             ],
>             refresh: true,
>         }),
>     ],
> });
> ```

***Second option:* Seperate out the laravel core files into their own directory and also rename the public/ directory, for laravel 9:**

1. Rename public folder to `public_html` (or any desired name)
2. Create a `laravel-core` directory and move all files and folders except `public_html` into the laravel-core folder.
3. Edit `index.php` in `public_html` folder and find/replace `__DIR__.'/../` with `__DIR__.'/../laravel-core/` (3 cases)
4. Edit `AppServiceProvider.php` and add below code in register method:

> ```
> $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
>   return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
> });
> ```

5. Add `publicDirectory: 'public_html'` to `laravel-core/vite.config.js` within the plugins / laravel object, eg.

> ```
> export default defineConfig({
>     plugins: [
>         laravel({
>             publicDirectory: '../public_html',
>             input: [
>                 'resources/sass/app.scss',
>                 'resources/js/app.js',
>             ],
>             refresh: true,
>         }),
>     ],
> });
> ```

Comment: thanks, the following help me as well https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#advanced-customization

Comment: If you're using Laravel 10, replace the code in AppServiceProvider with: app()->usePublicPath(base_path().'/../public_html'); Per the upgrade guide: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#public-path-binding

Answer (score 0):

For me the solutions above worked partially.
This is how I made it for Laravel 10 with the Vite plugin, so it works on the server but also to serve it locally through artisan.

Rename `public` to `public_html`
In `vite.config.js` add `publicDirectory: 'public_html'`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            publicDirectory: 'public_html',
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

In `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function register()
{
    app()->usePublicPath(realpath(base_path().'/public_html'));
}
```

And for some reason `php artisan storage:link` stops working after this, solved it like this, go to `/foo` to make the simlink or run it in the terminal if you have access.

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    shell_exec('ln -sfn /path/to/storage/app/public/ /path/to/public_html/storage');
});
```