# how to set public_path in Laravel 9 on the shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 9 project and I have following public_path with image access in the blade file

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path('images/logo.png')) }}" alt="" style="width: 300px; max-width: 600px; height: auto; margin: auto; display: block;">
```

this is working fine in my localhost and I have images folder in default public folder in the Laravel. but when I deploy My project to the shared hosting Hostgrator Laravel project public folder containts goes to the `public_html` folder. any way my other images are working well in live server but above image path not working and encounted following error message

```
Swift_IoException Unable to open file for reading [/home3/abc/abc/public/images/logo.png]
```

I think it is because public_path in the image script. then how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change public/ directory name in Laravel 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020327/how-do-i-change-public-directory-name-in-laravel-9)

Comment: Another method. If your server is Linux, you may also use symbolic link to make `public_html` an alias to `public`. But this probably requires you to know Linux and bash environment.

Answer (score 0):

public_path just give you nothing don't use this.

**First**

You should create a symbolic file in public directory. Maybe use `php artisan storage:link` on root folder using ssh or create symbolic file `ls -n ../stroage/app/public storage` on public directory

For laravel if you like to change public directory

- Set directory in vite.config.js
- Copy public directory item to new path
- Change the path that work in new path there are 5+ link there

**For Shared Hosting leave directory. Like if you like to use github which directory run on the root on server. Use public_html**

Laravel Shared hosting mean you don't have access to apache2 conf and more setting you have to use .htaccess on home.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

You don't have to change anything else. Just save in public dir on storage and access /storage/ in src

**How to use image store in /storage/app/public/photo/xyz.img ? Public data**

You should store public file in  /storage/app/public/ and create a symbolic link on public file name storage then You use `<img src"/storage/photo/xyz.img">`

or authenticated needed file use response file in your routes with some middleware

Comment: could you explain more what should I do exactly. Actually I can't understand well what did you mean Sir?

Comment: @amaruwakoi where you save files or which is your public storage folder

Comment: @amaruwakoi i update little bit for more context