# Deploying Laravel/Vue/Vite web app struggling "with server responded with a MIME type of "text/html""

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, manifest.json

I am new to web development and trying to deploy a website I have created with these tech stacks. I have had it running locally, and then ran the npm run build to generate the manifest.json file.

Locally the website works fine, however when i take it to the internet I get this error.
"
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
"

The website it not returning the .js or .css files and rather the index.blade.php html text.

Here are some parts of my code, starting with the index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        @vite('resources/css/bootstrap.min.css')        
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

        
        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id="app" class="container-sm">App not working...</div>
    </body>

    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</html>
```

Here is the manifest.json file

```
{
  "resources/css/app.css": {
    "file": "assets/app-X8Z-xCxC.css",
    "isEntry": true,
    "src": "resources/css/app.css"
  },
  "resources/css/bootstrap.min.css": {
    "file": "assets/bootstrap-Sq5YoTzA.css",
    "isEntry": true,
    "src": "resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  },
  "resources/js/app.js": {
    "file": "assets/app-T_x8cpmq.js",
    "isEntry": true,
    "src": "resources/js/app.js"
  }
}
```

I greatly appreciate any help as i have been struggling with this for a day now.

I have tried looking at the network tab on chrome inspect to see if it was retrieving the .js and .css files, however it was returning 200, and the index.blade.php html text.

When i look at the same thing locally, it returns the correct js or css file.

Comment: Look on the server in your `public/assets` directory. Are the built files there as you'd expect?

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, I have looked and it is correct. public/build/assets/ and in there is the files app-T_x8cpmq.js, app-X8Z-xCxC.css, bootstrap-Sq5YoTzA.css

Comment: And the requests you see in your browser are to `https://example.com/build/assets/app-T_x8cpmq.js`? And they're not loading the static assets? If not, you've got a server misconfiguration.

Comment: No they arent. It is down as *domain*/build/assets/app-T_x8cpmq.js but opens up the index html. It feel like we are getting down to the route of the issue, however I dont understand why it works locally when i use http://localhost:8000/build/assets/app-T_x8cpmq.js

Comment: The website i hosted on infinityfree.com, I have done npm run build, and changed the index.php file to point to the correct files. Have I missed a step in deploying the website?

Comment: In what way did you change the `index.php`?

Comment: Just since I moved my public files directly to the htdocs, I changed the routing for maintenance, vendor and bootstrap. I removed the ../ since it no longer needed to go back a directory to access public files

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that moving your files around from the standard structure is the cause of this. You're saying you moved `index.php` out of the `public` directory? That you put all Laravel files right in your `htdocs` folder? If so, that's a) the cause of this and b) insecure.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out. I had seen on a tutorial to do this, that is just extract the public contents into the main laravel app directory, however I will revert it back to how it should be with the standard framework and let you know if that fixes it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thankyou for your help so far! Reverting the structure back has worked somewhat. Now when I open the website, if I add /public to the url it opens up as i would expect with the css and js loading. This is beyond the scope of my original question, but could you help me or how to setup the .htaccess before the htdoc to point it to the right folder when you search the url, since the normal url has a 403 error.

Comment: `htdocs` is your `public` folder, basically. Put everything in `public` within `htdocs`. Everything else should be **above** `htdocs`. Then, follow instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020327/how-do-i-change-public-directory-name-in-laravel-9 at the accepted answer to tell Laravel and Vite where your modified public path is.