# Laravel + vite deploy manifest.json is not found?

Tags: laravel, vite, manifest.json

I am developing a project with Laravel + vite. When I run the "npm run build" command while developing on localhost, the @vite build folder goes to the "root/public/build/manifest.json" folder by default. But in cpanel there is no public folder, instead there is public_html. That's why I'm getting manifest.json not found error. How do I change the path of the manifest file to "root/public_html/build/manifest.json"?
I have shared a screenshot below regarding the error.
[This is ss from error page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuV9j.png)

How do I change the path of the manifest file to "root/public_html/build/manifest.json"?

Comment: Did you check any SO questions about this? Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74656919

Comment: or this github: https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/issues/74